# Selenium moveToElement() is not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mouseout

After testing logging in https://www.pcbway.com/ I want to test logout. 
[image]

In order to do this I need to hover on a div so that the sign out button appears. I tried using 
`Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).build().perform();`
but it did not work. I tried using the javascript exector
`JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);`

but it also did not work. I can see that the hover works by using mouseout jquery (screenshot below)[image]

I am using chrome 58 with selenium 3.4.0.

Comment: Have you tried adding `.build().perform()` to your Actions way?

Comment: yes of course, I have

Comment: You should show the code, and the browser you are working on

Comment: I added the code and browser

Comment: How do you get the Element variable?

Comment: using xpath //div[@class='nav-ubox']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to force it open by adding the class the element receives when the menu is open.

```
executor.executeScript("$('.nav-user-account').addClass('user-account-unfold')")
```

Then you can click the element in the menu.

Comment: executor.executeScript("$('.nav-ubox').addClass('nav-ubox-active')"); worked. I love you man